# Preg_replace index in array in replacement with pattern $arr[{...}]

Tags: php, arrays, replace, preg-replace

```
$month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',  'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
$str = "The fly went away in 1990-11-20";
$pattern = array('/(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/');
$replacement = array('${3}.'.'$month[\2 -1]<-- I don't know'.' ${1}');
$res = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
echo $res;
```

The result should be "The fly went away in 20.November 1990". (I know the pattern could be 0000-00-00. But that's ok for now). What is here the replacement for "$month[\2 -1]"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use preg_replace directly. Try this

```
function doReplace($matches) {
    $month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',  'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    return $matches[3] . ' ' . $month[$matches[2] - 1] . ' ' . $matches[1];
}

$str = "The fly went away in 1990-11-20";
$pattern = array('/(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/');
$res = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'doReplace', $str);
echo $res;
```

Uses [preg_replace_callback](https://php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-replace-callback.php) - see the manual for more info.

Comment: This is answer is useful! (Sorry, at the moment I can't upvote this answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
           $pattern,
           function (array $matches) use ($month) {
              return $matches[3].'.'.$month[$matches[2]-1].' '.$matches[1];
           },
           $str
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this working example, It will give you the desired **output**

```
    //echo date('d.F Y',strtotime('1990-11-20 00:00:00'));
    $month = array('','January','February','March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',  'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    $str = "The fly went away in 1990-11-20";
    $pattern = array('/(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/');
    $replacement = array('${3}.'.$month[12-1].' ${1}');
    $res = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
    echo $res;
```

Comment: What about the date `2014-05-15`?